# How do i take user input of an Arithmetic Expression like 5-8+7*4-8+9 or 1+5?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, while-loop, multiple-input

I am solving a problem for finding maximum value of an arithmetic expression. But I am having problem in taking input for the expression as no of characters are not fixed.

**Input Format:**

- The only line of the input contains a string s of length 2n + 1 for
  some n, with symbols s0 , s1 , . . . , s2n.
- Each symbol at an even position of s is a digit (that is, an integer from 0 to 9)
- while each symbol at an odd position is one of three operations from {+,-,*}.

But I want digits and symbols in different arrays(digits in an int array and operations in a char array) for my solution.

This is how I implemented originally:

```
  string s;
  std::cin >> s;

  n=s.size();
  cout<<"n= "<<n<<endl;

  vector<long long> no;
  vector<char> ops;

  for(int i = 0; i <n; i++)
  {
    if(i%2==0)
    {
      no.push_back(s[i]);
    }
    else{
      ops.push_back(s[i]);
    }
  }
```

But I am not being able to get required input, instead getting this:

```
INPUT:
5-8+7*4-8+9

OUTPUT:
n = 11
no[0] = 53
no[1] = 56
no[2] = 55
no[3] = 52
no[4] = 56
no[5] = 57
ops[0] = -
ops[1] = +
ops[2] = *
ops[3] = -
ops[4] = +
```

I have also tried one more solution:

```
  vector<long long> no;
  vector<char> ops;

  int i=0;
  while(cin)
  {

    cout<<"i= "<<i<<endl;
    if(i%2==0)
    {
      int s;
      cin>>s;
      if(s=='\0')
      {
        exit();
      }
      cout<<"s= "<<s<<endl;
      no.push_back((int)s);
      cout<<"no= "<<no[i/2]<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
      char s;
      cin>>s;
      if(s=='\0')
      {
        exit();
      }
      cout<<"s= "<<s<<endl;
      ops.push_back(s);
      cout<<"ops= "<<ops[(i-1)/2]<<endl;
    }
    i++;
  }
```

But this goes into infinite loop.

Please help me out

Comment: "But I am not being able to get required input, instead getting this:" Okay, now think carefully about what exactly is wrong with it. Do you see a pattern in how the `no` array values are different from what you expect? Now, how are you getting the values that are put into `no`? Do you understand how this causes the problem?

Comment: I can see there is a pattern but unable to conclude why is it happening. I wanna know how to correctly get the values in `no`.

Comment: What happens if you try something like `int x = '3'; cout << x << endl;` (be careful of the single quotes)? What is your understanding of what a `char` actually is, in C++? Are you familiar with the concept of ASCII?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Great work and admirable patience. Please keep explaining. When you create any kind of answer here let me know. I will do my best to consider it upvoteable. (I notice that you are probably beyond craving reputation, but nevertheless.... )

Comment: Thank you. I understood what you were saying. I forgot to do type conversion but even after it was giving same result. One of my friend now have told me to use ` ( s[i] - '0' ) ` which solved my problem but why ascii value of 0 was added to the digits is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output seems to be correct, but as already mentioned in the comments, your values are read as characters, not as digits, so a conversion needs to be done.

In order to do this, it might be helpful to understand that, in ASCII, the digits have following value:

```
Character ASCII-code value
      '0'         48     0
      '1'         49     1
      '2'         50     2
      '3'         51     3
      '4'         52     4
      '5'         53     5
      '6'         54     6
      '7'         55     7
      '8'         56     8
      '9'         57     9
```

How to get the value out of the character value? Easy :

```
value(<character>) = ASCII_code(<character>) - ASCII_code('0'), or:
                   = ASCII_code(<character>) - 48
```